# How to get the arguments of a decorator function?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-decorators

I have a command with a decorator `@commands.has_role("admin")` and I need to get that role. This is what I have tried:

```py
filtered = await self.filter_commands(self.context.bot.commands, sort=True) 
checks = [command.checks for command in filtered]
for check in checks:
  for c in check:
    print(c.role)
```

but returns `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'role'`.
How do I get the value of that decorator? This decorator is not custom, it is part of `discord.py`[(discord.ext.commands)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20has_role#discord.ext.commands.has_role)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the value of an argument passed to a decorator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917991/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-an-argument-passed-to-a-decorator-in-python)

Comment: No. The decorator is not custom.

Comment: The value isn't necessarily *stored* anywhere; it may only be used long enough to create the decorator that its applied to you function.

Comment: Looking at the source code the role is not stored in a acessible variable, it's in the locals of the function.

Comment: But when I use `c.__code__.co_varnames`, it returns `('ctx', 'role')` @chepner

Comment: does `c.__closure__[0 or more].cell_contents` provide you with something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes necessary values are stored in attributes of the wrapper. Not for the discord wrapper.

Decorators make use of closures. To find their closed values use

```
function.__closure__[0].cell_contents
```

function here is `c`